# how to remove spaces added with a values with the array elements?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am having a major problem with an `Array` values, which are added with spaces when they were added to the array. So is there any way to remove such spaces means using `Trim` in a single line of statement, before they are used in further processing, otherwise I would need to use `Trim` in every calculations. So any quicker process to remove such spaces one time within the `code`?

```
Dim VMHArray
VMHArray = Array("VMH All Fields Review - Add Supplier  Emergency", _
                 "VMH All Fields Review  (Req. Provides Supplier Details) - Update/Enable Supplier", _
                 "VMH Triggered Final Sourcing Review - Add Address_Direct", _
                 "Activate / Create supplier in business system - Add Address", _
                 "Activate / Create supplier in Business System - Add Supplier")
```

Comment: You found Trim not a solution? Can you then show where your problem is? Maybe a small code sample?

Comment: @rene I think you didn't follow my statement. What i said is with that array i have many calculations at many places,every where i had to use `Trim` which i think - I am doing such a task repeatedly,so i am wondering a way to remove the spaces if any at the first places before started my series of calculations. The array has been assigned values at its declaration time.The array has 350 elements!

Comment: @VBSlover: Could you add the code for declaring the array and the loaded values to your question? Maybe not all 350 elements, but at least some of them.

Comment: @JüriRuut please see my description!

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you have a comma separated list of strings, which may contain unwanted spaces? I'd use Search/Replace of some text editor.

Comment: I used but still some places they were not removed,so it causes in the main script too much data discrepancies. So i would like to solve it in programmatic way,so that every time when i would pre-load such array not required to do remove such spaces manually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you clean up the array after initialization, like so:

```
Sub test()
   Dim a(2) As String
   a(0) = "t1"
   a(1) = "t2  "
    a(2) = "test3 "
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim trimmed As Variant

    trimmed = TrimArray(a)

     For i = 0 To UBound(trimmed)
         Debug.Print trimmed(i) + "|"
     Next

End Sub

Function TrimArray(ByRef a() As String) As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
     a(i) = Trim(a(i))
    Next

    TrimArray = a
End Function
```

Comment: Any good chance to avoid such `Loop` and do the same in a direct approach if any?

Comment: @VBSlover what do you mean by `direct approach`?  Are you asking about triming all values in the array in 1 line without looping?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes! that i am asking!

Comment: @VBSlover the closest I think you can get to this is to write the application in a `.NET` language and deploy it as an Excel add-in.  If you do that, you can make use of LINQ to rewrite this in a single line (although technically there would still be a loop, just internal to the LINQ query).  If you stick with VBA, looping is your only alternative.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree with you,If you see the main description there, i added a code. Now you can see that in the code itself all the original values itself has spaces between them - whic are actual.But my problem is created by the spaces that are padded at first and last to them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 i can't change the platform where i am developing my code,its a ongoing project!

Comment: @rene give me an VBScript quivalent  code. It is not working!

Answer (score 4):

Trim the values as they are inserted into the array. Or, alternatively, loop over the array, trim each element and reinsert the trimmed element into the array.

Comment: the array loaded at its declaration time! it is not on run time!

Answer (score 1):

My VBE didn't accept 350 entries in an array.

However, for VBA works the code below with a reduced set:

```
Sub main()

Dim VMHArray As Variant

VMHArray = Array("VMH All Fields Review - Add Supplier  Emergency", _
"VMH All Fields Review (Req. Provides Supplier Details) - Update/Enable Supplier", _
"VMH Triggered Final Sourcing Review - Add Address_Direct", _
"Activate - / Create supplier in business system - Add Address", _
"Activate /Create supplier in Business System - Add Supplier", _
"Activate / Create supplier in Business System -Add Supplier Emergency")

VMHArray = TrimArrayElements(VMHArray)

End Sub

Function TrimArrayElements(InputArray As Variant) As Variant

  Dim arr_element As Variant

  For Each arr_element In InputArray
    arr_element = Trim(arr_element)
  Next

End Function
```

Comment: is there any chance by your code to remove spaces within the data also,which I don't want.I just want to remove trailing and preceding spaces if any for each array elements!

Comment: AFAIK, `Trim` removes preceding and trailing spaces. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php

Comment: is the `Loop` only `must to use` technique here?

Comment: The other is Search/Replace, as proposed earlier. Here are some comparisons concerning looping times: http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/797078-next-vs-do-loop-winner. You could measure the time consumed by cycling, if that's your main concern.

Comment: May I have some help on the post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085891/excel-dashboard-creation

Comment: Start with Excel Chart Wizard, try Pie chart.

Comment: Can you reopen the post from your end?

Comment: No. I guess it needs 5 votes, I cannot cast a single one. If you google `VBA chart`, you'll find a mass of instructions.